# BIRT dyanamic image report generation

Tags: image, dynamic, birt

In my database I have table `Rapid_Slum_Appraisal`

```
id | general_info_left_image  
--------------------------------------
 1 | http://127.0.0.1/media/image1.jpg  
 2 | http://127.0.0.1/media/image2.jpg
```

if you hit the URL you can see the image in browser.

I have created image.rptdesign file using BIRT designer.In it I have created a data source and data set to retrieve general_info_left_image from database.

Step I followed -

1. First I created Data source and data set to retrieve image from database.
2. Then I drag image report item from toolbox to create dynamic image.
3. when set data type to Blob and try to view the report using BIRT Viewer,I see below error and image is not displayed.

> Can not convert the value of
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/2697dd7fdfef2c54b6bbc4698ec14b8e_7rRHk5J.jpg
>   to Binary type

4. when I set data type to string the image is not displayed

image.rptdesign file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122</property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">96</property>
    <data-sources>
        <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" name="django" id="4">
            <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>metadataBidiFormatStr</name>
                    <value>ILYNN</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>disabledMetadataBidiFormatStr</name>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>contentBidiFormatStr</name>
                    <value>ILYNN</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>disabledContentBidiFormatStr</name>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>
            <property name="odaDriverClass">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
            <property name="odaURL">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/django</property>
            <property name="odaUser">postgres</property>
            <encrypted-property name="odaPassword" encryptionID="base64">c29mdGNvcm5lcg==</encrypted-property>
        </oda-data-source>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <oda-data-set extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JdbcSelectDataSet" name="image" id="5">
            <property name="nullsOrdering">nulls lowest</property>
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">general_info_left_image</property>
                    <property name="analysis">dimension</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">general_info_left_image</text-property>
                    <text-property name="heading">general_info_left_image</text-property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">general_info_left_image</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">django</property>
            <list-property name="resultSet">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="name">general_info_left_image</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">general_info_left_image</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <xml-property name="queryText"><![CDATA[select general_info_left_image 
from public.master_rapid_slum_appraisal]]></xml-property>
            <xml-property name="designerValues"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model:DesignValues xmlns:design="http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/connectivity/oda/design" xmlns:model="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/report/model/adapter/odaModel">
  <Version>2.0</Version>
  <design:ResultSets derivedMetaData="true">
    <design:resultSetDefinitions>
      <design:resultSetColumns>
        <design:resultColumnDefinitions>
          <design:attributes>
            <design:identifier>
              <design:name>general_info_left_image</design:name>
              <design:position>1</design:position>
            </design:identifier>
            <design:nativeDataTypeCode>12</design:nativeDataTypeCode>
            <design:precision>100</design:precision>
            <design:scale>0</design:scale>
            <design:nullability>NotNullable</design:nullability>
            <design:uiHints>
              <design:displayName>general_info_left_image</design:displayName>
            </design:uiHints>
          </design:attributes>
          <design:usageHints>
            <design:label>general_info_left_image</design:label>
            <design:formattingHints>
              <design:displaySize>100</design:displaySize>
            </design:formattingHints>
          </design:usageHints>
        </design:resultColumnDefinitions>
      </design:resultSetColumns>
      <design:criteria/>
    </design:resultSetDefinitions>
  </design:ResultSets>
</model:DesignValues>]]></xml-property>
        </oda-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
    <body>
        <table id="6">
            <property name="dataSet">image</property>
            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">general_info_left_image</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">general_info_left_image</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["general_info_left_image"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <column id="15"/>
            <header>
                <row id="7">
                    <cell id="8"/>
                </row>
            </header>
            <detail>
                <row id="10">
                    <cell id="11">
                        <image id="16">
                            <property name="dataSet">image</property>
                            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                                <structure>
                                    <property name="name">general_info_left_image</property>
                                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["general_info_left_image"]</expression>
                                    <property name="dataType">blob</property>
                                    <property name="allowExport">true</property>
                                </structure>
                            </list-property>
                            <property name="source">expr</property>
                            <expression name="valueExpr">row["general_info_left_image"]</expression>
                        </image>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </detail>
            <footer>
                <row id="13">
                    <cell id="14"/>
                </row>
            </footer>
        </table>
    </body>
</report>
```

System Information:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
BIRT  4.6.0
Java Version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: with what function did you retrieve the image data from the database? What error are you getting? Did you activate all the logging? What version of BIRT are you using?

Comment: I am using  BIRT 4.6.0

Comment: what exactly have you tried. It is impossible to give advise at this point. Please update your post with answers to my previous questions

Comment: show us the code in the datasource open and fetch script.  Show us the error in your debug logs

Comment: I am using BIRT designer application BIRT 4.6.0 to design the BIRT report and BIRT viewer which is hosted on apache tomcat to view report.

Comment: the images are unreadable. Please add the code to your question.

Comment: I have updated the blog post if the screen-shot are still unreadable you press Ctrl plus plus to zoom in.

Comment: please find code http://pastebin.com/W1LC1cFT

Comment: ok, thx. Now point us to your dataset and output column that should contain the image. Also give us the ID of the field that should display the image. I can't find it in your 7 datasets

Comment: I've noticed that all datatypes are set to STRING, INTEGER, NUMBER.... the image you try to get from the database should be a BLOB/CLOB

Comment: I tried doing that I got error  :                                                                           org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information. Can not convert the value of ./2697dd7fdfef2c54b6bbc4698ec14b8e.jpg to Binary type.

Comment: you are not answering obvious questions. what dataset, what field, what is the ID on the canvas? I cant help you like this. From the looks of it, you are retrieving just the filename, not the image itself. I'm done.

Comment: check the code you pasted. The word "image" is only in there to set DPI. There is no dataset called image, there is no output column called general_info_left_image. You shouldn't use external blogs to post info that needs be in your question. The images you posted are unreadable. You've obviously put some effort in it, but in this way you wont find many others trying to help out.

Comment: okay got your commitment. i will update it in question.

Comment: I have updated the question. I really appreciate your time. Any help in resolution this would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I can see where the confusion comes in. From the database you are not retrieving the actual image, but just its location.

For this to work, you have to make sure that for everybody viewing the report, the link is accessible. (ie you can just paste the link in your browser and you should see the image)

steps to fix the report:

1. Remove the dataset from the image. You want it to get data via the table it is in, so set it to None.
2. The table is has the general_info_left_image set to string, just as in the dataset, so this is correct. No changes needed.
3. Select the image and set 'Select from image' to URI
4. Enter URI, select javascript syntax and you enter the expression builder.
5. Select available column bindings, select table, select general_info_left_image (double click to add it to the expression). Your expression should read : row["general_info_left_image"]

This should work. Good luck.

Comment: It works .thank you for your valuable time and support.

Comment: I was able to view image in BIRT viewer but when i try to generate report in pdf format it display message "The resource of this report item is not reachable."

Comment: Did you mean the PDF output in BIRT? If yes, use debugger options to find out the exact URI that is used. If you mean PDF output form your actual reporting application you should open a new question with a proper problem description.

Comment: actually I was able to see images when i use option generate report as HTML. when I use option generate report as pdf its display message "The resource of this report item is not reachable."